# How to set full screen mode in iPod

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am using full screen layout in my iOS App, its working fine in iPhone and iPad.
But app showing strange behaviour in iPod. When I run app in iPod half inch black screen comes in top and bottom bar.

In my storyboard setting I have following

```
status bar -> none
top bar ->none
bottom bar -> none
```

Also set the value in info.plist

```
view-status bar controller -> No
```

How I can set full screen layout for iPod?

Comment: iPad or iPod ? I found you mixed iPod with iPad .

Comment: iPod sorry I am updating question

Comment: you add Default-568h@2x.png it for iphone5 or ipod

Comment: its working fine in iphone 5 but not in ipod, I am using only one Default image yet. Does it force view to use other screen height?

Comment: you have to handle both 3.5" and 4" layout using Auto Layout with Constraints

Comment: check your xib, either you are using 3.5 full screen or 4 full screen

Comment: I am using storyboard

Comment: @kirtimali Thanks I have placed images for 4 inch screen and then problem solved. Thanks alot. You may post answer so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Default-568h@2x.png it for 4-inch iPhone5 or iPod

Answer (score 0):

if u r using storyboard, there is one option to design view for 3.5 and 4 full screen.

if you are selecting 3.5 or 4 screen, go to **size inspector** and adjust the **origin** and **Autosizing** as per the screen shot below.

Note: This is just an example for how to set design in 3.5 and 4 screen

// check the screen shot below

[image]